# Pixel-wise like assignment In Matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

Is there any good way to assignment some masked pixels with the same color except `for-loop`?

```ml
%% pick a color
cl = uisetcolor; %1-by-3 vector

im = ones(3, 3, 3)  / 2; % gray image

mask = rand(3, 3); 
mask_idx = mask > 0.5; % create a mask

%% Something like this
im(mask_idx, :) = cl'; % assignment the pixels to color `cl`
```

Comment: you can `reshape` your image, apply mask, and reshape back... if that's what you mean

Comment: @natan I have added my own solution using `repmat()`, but it is a bit awkward. If you have an easier solution using `reshape()` I would love to see it.

Comment: A combination of `reshape`, `permute` and `repmat` are needed. Look them all up on documentation.

Comment: sorry, seems that a for-loop over the number of channels would be both easier to understand and actually faster.

Comment: @rwong yes, finally I chose `for-loop` over the channels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this making use of `repmat()`:

```
%% pick a color
cl = uisetcolor; %1-by-3 vector
im = ones(3, 3, 3)/2; % gray image
mask = rand(3, 3);
mask_idx = mask > 0.5; % create a mask

cl_rep = repmat(cl,[sum(mask_idx(:)) 1]);
im(repmat(mask_idx,[1 1 3])) = cl_rep(:);
```

What I have done is to repeat the mask three times to get all three layers of the image. To be able to match this with the colour-vector `cl` it also has to be repeated. The number of times it is repeated is the same as the amount of pixels that are to be changed, `sum(mask_idx(:))`.

Comment: Yes, this is quite similar to the idea of `deal()`. Thanks for your solution :)